# Is UIWebView will continue in iOS 17?

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, ios17

My question is related to ios 17. Is apple allow apps to continue UIWebView? Is anyone have information about this? ios 17 beta has been released.

Comment: WKWebView has been around since iOS 8. UIWebView was deprecated in iOS 12. Certainly if you are actively putting out updates to an app you really should switch from UIWebView to WKWebView. If you are asking about an old app that hasn't been updated in a while then it should continue to work. But in some future iOS update it could stop working if Apple officially removes it from UIKit (which they have done very, very rarely).

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is [deprecated and should not be used](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview). Versions including iOS 17 should instead use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). Apple has [officially said](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132174) they will reject the use of UIWebView.

That being said, you can still use UIWebView in iOS 17 [(this person is doing it, for example)](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732976)

Comment: I have an existing application so please let me know if the current application will work.

Comment: @ShahbazAkram You still can. I misunderstood your initial question, sorry. I have updated my response accordingly so you may mark it as the answer.